# ajax success: function (msg) undefined

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, html

Hello i have this script that returns msg undefined. In consol it returns jsondata but when i do an alert or when i'm trying to verify it, it does not work.

```
$(function() {
    $(".aplica_bt").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        $.ajax({
            url: href,

            datatype: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg.exista);
                if (msg.exista == "yes") {
                    alert('ai aplicat');
                }
                if (msg.aplicat == "yes") {
                    $('#modal_succes').modal('show');
                }
            },
        });
    });
});
```

[image]

also here is the php code that returns json

```
<?php

$id_c=$_GET['id_c'];
$id_j=$_GET['id_j'];

$stmt=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Aplicatii where id_c=:id_c and id_j=:id_j");
$stmt->bindParam(":id_c",$id_c);
$stmt->bindParam("id_j",$id_j);
$stmt->execute();
if($row=$stmt->fetch())
{
     $arr = array('exista'  => 'yes');
     echo json_encode($arr);
}
else
{
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Aplicatii (id_c,id_j) VALUES (:id_c,:id_j)");
$stmt->bindParam(":id_c",$id_c);
$stmt->bindParam("id_j",$id_j);
$stmt->execute();
 $arr = array('aplicat'  => 'yes');
     echo json_encode($arr);
}
?>
```

And the response of `console.log`:

```
{"exista":"yes"}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(msg);` return?

Comment: `{"exista":"yes"}`

Comment: So it returns a `string` and not an `object`? Then `msg.exista` has to be `undefined`.

Comment: are you sure it is in success?

Comment: it returns json object

Comment: But when `console.log` returns `{"exista":"yes"}` it is not an `object`. So whats true now?

Comment: damn you're right thnx, i didn't add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` in my php file. Thnx for opening my eyes

Comment: Ok, good it workes now. ;)

Comment: You should add your answer to help others and community

Comment: I've made it an answer, @shivgre

Comment: @eisbehr, thanks could you consider adding comment to the other answer I gave recently which you might have downvoted

Comment: did you parse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `console.log(msg)` returns `{"exista":"yes"}` it is not an `object`, it is a `string`. So trying to access a property, like `msg.exista`, will return `undefined`.

This could be happen when you set a wrong `dataType` in your AJAX request, what is correctly set to `JSON` in your example.

So the probleme is on PHP side, you need to add the correct `Content-Type` to the response `headers`.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

aside

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

another way to solve this error is to parse your ajax response

```
msg = JSON.parse(msg);
```